# Constant value required for VHDL array indexing?

Tags: vhdl, signal, synthesis

I basically have a line like this in a vhdl code.

```
entity my_entity is
   port(x : in std_logic_vector;
        y : in std_logic_vector;
        ...);
end entity my_entity;

architecture arch of my_entity is
   -- declarations...
   signal delta : unsigned(...); --correct sizing
   signal aux_signal : std_logic; -- correct sizing
   signal another_signal : unsigned(...); --correct sizing
begin
   delta <= x - y; -- x > y
   aux_signal <= or_reduce(std_logic_vector(another_signal(to_integer(delta) downto 1)));
   -- other stuff
end architecture arch;
```

the syntax is fine (checked by ncvhdl), however when i try the synthesis the compiler complaints of assignement like "aux_signal" saying that it needs a constant value.

Since i need an assignment like that... is there another way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff's `for` loop is the correct approach here, but you don't have to embed it in a process : it can be a function instead, and most synthesis tools (possibly not all!) should handle it correctly.

```
function or_reduce_select (sig : unsigned; mask : natural) return std_logic is
  variable or_result : std_logic;
begin
  or_result := '0';
  for i in 1 to sig'left loop
    if i <= mask then
      or_result := or_result or sig(i);
    end if;
  end loop;
  return or_result;
end or_reduce_select;

...

aux_signal <= or_reduce_select(another_signal, to_integer(delta));
```

EDIT re: comments...
The original requires different hardware for different values of Delta. As Delta varies at runtime that requires hardware to appear and disappear at runtime.

Look at the loop here : the bounds `1 to sig'left` are constant so the hardware is fixed : instead, the "if" condition masks each unwanted bit with an AND gate - the gate is always there, its other input is variable at runtime. Thus, this form is physically realisable in hardware, while the original form isn't.

Perhaps it's easier to visualise the hardware this will generate if we rewrite the loop:

```
  for i in 1 to sig'left loop
    if i <= mask then
      or_result := or_result or sig(i);
    end if;
  end loop;
```

in the following form

```
  for i in 1 to sig'left loop
    or_result := (or_result or sig(i)) and (i <= mask); 
  end loop;
```

Comment: May i ask why function and loop work in such case while concurrent assignment doesn't? i'm missing the logic behind this.

Comment: The function call IS a concurrent assignment (or it can be used in a process as well)

Comment: Ok... than i don't understand the problem with my statement why instead embedding it (or equivalently...) it works. I don't understand what kind of problem you avoid in this manner, and why you can avoid in this manner.

Comment: Jeff answered the problem with your current statement. It requires different hardware for different values of Delta. As Delta varies at runtime that requires hardware to appear and disappear at runtime. Look at the loop here : the bounds `1 to sig'left` are constant so the hardware is fixed : instead, the "if" condition masks each unwanted bit with an AND gate - the gate is always there, its other input is variable at runtime. Thus, this form is physically realisable in hardware, hile the original form isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
another_signal(to_integer(delta) downto 1)
```

Slices with runtime-variable bounds are not supported by synthesis. How would this translate into real hardware?

You could achieve a similar function using a loop within a process:

```
process (delta, another_signal)
  variable or_result : std_logic;
begin
  or_result := '0';
  for i in 1 to another_signal'left loop
    if (i <= to_integer(delta)) then
      or_result := or_result or another_signal(i);
    end if;
  end loop;
  aux_signal <= or_result;
end process;
```

If you can't use a process, and the size of `another_signal` is fixed, you could write something like:

```
aux_signal <= another_signal(1) when delta = 1 else
              or_reduce(another_signal(2 downto 1) when delta = 2 else
              or_reduce(another_signal(3 downto 1) when delta = 3 else
              or_reduce(another_signal(4 downto 1) when delta = 4 else
              '0';
```

I would strongly encourage you to use processes, even for asynchronous logic.

Comment: It's a combinatorial design, i would like to avoid process (even if the process doesn't synthesize any FF or register). Can i use a function instead?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to avoid using the `process` construct?

Comment: Don't be mad at me xD. Just because i'm used to use process usually with sequential designs.

Comment: @Lukkio I edited to add a possible solution for the 'not using a process' case.

Comment: So in the second case i necessarily have to use "listing" of all the case? i thought it was easier...

Comment: Would that be possible instead to use a resize function (based on the delta value) and than the or_reduce on the result? (from [this link](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cgebotys/NEW/numeric_std_vhd.htm))

Comment: Is your process correct? i mean you make signal assignment there in terms assignment is semantically correct (for what i need to do)?

Comment: I think using `resize` would result in the same problem of the parameter not being constant. I updated the answer to show a complete process.

Comment: I've tried your process... it doesn't work. Internally it has an if statement like <code>if delta < 3</code> and that line gives me the same error...